# FxCop custom rule requiring validation of parameters

Tags: c#, static-analysis, fxcop

I'm trying to make a custom FxCop rule that will test for calls to the indexer getter of Request.QueryString without a previous call (in the same method) to a certain validation method from our project's Utilities module.

The documentation I've found is not in-depth enough to get me where I need to go. Is there some doc that I'm missing? Or is it time for trial and error?

What I've seen:

http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/

http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163930.aspx

As well as all SO posts tagged FxCop with the word custom.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official SDK for FxCop rules.  The most complete single resource is http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/.  Pretty much all the available resources are geared toward helping one get started with the "wrapper" mechanics of creating rules.  None of them really cover the finicky details of how to create specific rule logic.  For that sort of thing, your best bet is to grab a decompiler like [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) so that you can see how the Microsoft-supplied rules are built.  Another helpful technique is to run your embryonic rules under the debugger so that you can see the objects and properties that are available at runtime.  If you get stuck with some particular part of a rule implementation, you can always ask about it either here or on the [FxCop forum maintained by Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/threads/).